# React Native using Cookies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cookies, fetch, jsx

I have created a Login and a today page and I'm trying to implement cookies. When im login in i use username/password and it returns a cookie from an API. I now want to fetch data from another api via the cookie i retrieved through my login. How do i pass the cookie in react native?

my login.js page looks like this.

```
async login() {
    try { 
        let response = await fetch('http://192.168.168.114:8090/Cam/LoginOut/role', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              role: this.state.role,
              username: this.state.username,
              password: this.state.password
            })
        });
        let res = await response.text();
        if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            let headers = response.headers
            let newCookie = headers['Set-Cookie'];
            console.log(response.headers);
            console.log("res is + " + res);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Idag');
        } else {
            let errors = res;
            console.log(response.status + " fejl, Jeg er næsten inde");
            throw errors;
        }

    }   catch (errors) {
        console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ');
        // ADD THROW ERRORS EVENTUALLY
    }


}
```

and my today.js page fetch looks like this

```
componentDidMount = () => {
            try {

        let response = fetch('http://192.168.168.114:8090/Cam/Calendar/show', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
            from : "2019-02-20 08:00:00",
            to : "2019-02-21 17:00:00"
            })
        });
        let res = response.text();
        if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            //data fra svar her
            console.log("Today: res is + " + res);
        } else {
            let errors = res;
            console.log("Today: Jeg er næsten inde");
            throw errors;
        }

    }   catch (errors) {
        console.log('Today: There has been a problem with your Data: ');
        //this.dropdown.alertWithType('error', 'Error', error.message);
        //this.props.navigation.navigate('TodayScreen');
        // ADD THROW ERRORS EVENTUALLY
    }
```

};

it's in component did mount in my today.js so it will load as soon as the user logs in. (login works and i have a navigator to switch to other pages)

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot "touch" the cookie in a mobile context, at least this is what I have been thought when I faced the same issue 2 years ago. You cannot console.log the cookie value or anything like that. However, you can set this in your fetch method:

```
credentials: 'same-origin'
```

I am not sure if this will work for you as I was using the same API and I can see in your case you want to use a different one, but I think it's still worth a try! Good luck.

Comment: i should put this on both fetch method headers? or just login?

Comment: I added this for all the calls. So I had a fetch template which I was calling with different api urls, data etc. Every call I was making I added this line to the fetch.

Comment: ye i dont think it works:( i cant get the data from my second API. I dont think the cookie is "saved" and used automaticly again in the new api